# Deploy ear contains errors

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

I'm using WebSphere Application Developer Tools for Eclipse. How to deploy ear that contains errors? I'm remember checkbox with this option, but cannot find it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of error (and it's severity) it might not even be possible.

Some errors are simple configuration warnings, others are similar to your program didn't compile (and thus cannot run).

Comment: Yes, right you are. I have found this checkbox, but it don't helps me. 

`Preferences > Server > WebSphere Application Server > Allow applications containing errors to be published on a server`